# zsh: Arithmetic Expansion: 'syntax error: operand expected (error token is "1+1")'

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to increment the output of a zsh command called get_latest_release by 1.
Here's my code:

```
current_version=$(/bin/zsh -i -c get_latest_release) 
echo "current version = $current_version" # outputs 'current version = 1'
next=$(($current_version+1)) # gives an error: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "1+1")
echo $next
```

When I do:

```
current_version=1
echo "current version = $current_version" # displays current version = 1
next=$(($current_version+1))
echo $next # displays 2
```

Any idea why I can't get the output incremented by 1?

When I try:

```
/bin/zsh -i -c get_latest_release | hexdump -C
```

It strangely outputs the hexdump of the **path**: file://path_to_current_script.1.

So I just copied the get_latest_release() function to my script and it's now working! I really don't know why it's not working when the command is called with /bin/zsh.

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: zsh + oh-my-zsh on mac

Comment: Add output of `/bin/zsh -i -c get_latest_release | hexdump -C` to your question (no comment).

Comment: And what *is* that hex dump? We're looking for non-printable characters that `echo` itself doesn't show. (You can also try `declare -p current_version`.)

Comment: What is `get_latest_release`? A shell script?

Comment: @garys : While your statement is correct (just unnecessarily complicated; you could do a `((next=current_version+1))` instead), I guess that `current_version` does not contain just `1` in the failing case, and using `echo` is not a good way to verify this. Do a `xxd <<<$current_version` instead.

Comment: @garys: Also, your way of calculating `current_version` looks odd. Why not simply doing a `current_version=$(get_latest_release)`?

Comment: @user1934428 calling get_latest_release without specifying the zsh location doesn't work (the function is defined in the .zshrc file). But honestly simply copying that function to my script worked, so I'm pretty cool with it now :)

Comment: @chepner `declare -p current_version` returns `declare -- current_version="1"` but as stated it seems that moving the function get_latest_release to the sh file itself worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @garys : You did not say that it is a function, but you can't invoke a *function* directly, which is defined in a different file. You would have at least to source that file, so that the function gets defined in the scope of your script.